# how to connect to SQL Server through objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql-server, database

How I can connect to SQL Server from My Mobile Application  iOS Objective-C.

I got sample code for Android i.e

```
public void ConnectToDatabase(){
try {

     // SET CONNECTIONSTRING
     Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
     String username = "XXXXXXXXX";
        String password = "XXXXXX";
     Connection DbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.188.4.83:1433/DATABASE;user=" + username + ";password=" + password);

     Log.w("Connection","open");
    Statement stmt = DbConn.createStatement();
    ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery(" select * from users ");


     EditText num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.displaymessage);
    num.setText(reset.getString(1));

    DbConn.close();

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    Log.w("Error connection","" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

}

Please help me integrate the connextion in Objective-C as well.

Comment: Any solution ??